# Sonarint is not analyzing java program in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I have installed sonarlint plugin in vscode in extensions section. Now I want to analyze a java code opened in VSCode. Analyzing is not happening automatically.

Could someone guide me the steps?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, apart from having installed Java Runtime in your system, you also require  [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension in place to enable the support for Java.

Comment: yes, that's by default is installed. Anything apart from this? can you give me the documentation link

Comment: Java analyzer is available from SonarLint version 1.15.0, please make sure your analyzer has atleast version 1.15.0 
Documentation: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vscode